# Compile liberasurecode (missing libshss.so)

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, error-correction, forwarderrorcorrection

I have successfully compiled liberasurecode but I'm facing an issue when using python-pyeclib:

```
liberasurecode_instance_create: dynamic linking error libisal.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
liberasurecode_instance_create: dynamic linking error libshss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I saw [this](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/93267/unable-to-start-swift-proxy-liberasurecode-missing-libshssso/) problem but I'm not capable of pass this error
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work we uncover the problem was the input format, because some of the library give an error on the init if we set the unsupported combination of k, m.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

I meeted this problem today also,you should install pyeclib manually:

1.git clone https://bitbucket.org/kmgreen2/pyeclib.git`

2.sudo python setup.py install`

If you run *"swift-init proxy restart"* you will get this error:

> "ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyeclib_c.so:
>   undefined symbol: liberasurecode_backend_available"

Then run *"ldconfig"* or place this line:

3.export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

Start  swift again.
It worked for me.

Comment: I have pyeclib and liberasurecode both with the version from the master version of github. If you could give me more information I can try to test and help to debug this problem. Also I'm in the last version of ubuntu any help?
Witch OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

it is because the system can not find the needed lib.
execute this

```
vim /etc/ld.so.conf
```

then add /usr/local/lib to this file
at last execute

```
ldconfig
```

it works for me. try it